# Al usar uvicorn me da 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, error500, fastapi

Soy nuevo, estoy intentando aprender Python a través de los videos de Mouredev estoy siguiendo los pasos para hacer una API y me da error 500 al ejecutarlo en thunder para corroborar que funcione.

Les dejo el código, ha estoy usando Virtual Studio Code, Python 3.12.1 en windows 11 de 64 bits.

Lo raro es que si me funciona */Usersjson*, pero no */Users* ni */Users_list*.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

#python -m uvicorn users:app --reload
#para dejar de usar el servidor control c
class User: (BaseModel)
name: str
surname: str
url: str
age: int
@app.get("/Users_list")
async def Users_list():
   Users_list = [User(name="Flor", surname="Martin", url="https//mouredev.com", Age=9),
            User (name="Fede", surname="Martin", url="https//mouredev.com", Age=11),
            User (name="Mirian", surname="Herrera", url="https//mourede2.com", Age=49)]
           
@app.get("/Usersjson")

async def Usersjson():
    return [{"name": "Ariel", "surname": "Martin", "url": "https//mouredev.com", "Age":45},
{"name": "Flor", "surname": "Martin", "url": "https//mouredev.com", "Age":9},
{"name": "Fede", "surname": "Martin", "url": "https//mouredev.com", "Age":11},
{"name": "Mirian", "surname": "Herrera", "url": "https//mourede2.com", "Age":49}]

@app.get("/Users")
async def Users():
    return Users( name = "Ariel", surname="Martin", url="https//mouredev.com", Age=45)
```

debería darme `ok 200`, pero no sé cual es mi error, ya perdí la cuenta de cuantas veces retrocedí el video buscando el error y la verdad no encuentro, agradezco la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes unos cuantos errores:

- El primero esta en la definición del modelo de pydantic, tienes:

  ```
  User: (BaseModel)
  ```

  tienes los `:` en el lugar incorrecto, como si fuera notación de tipos, debes derivar de `BaseModel`:

  ```
  User(BaseModel):
  ```
- El segundo error esta tambien en la clase que define el modelo, tienes un error de sangrado al definir los atributos:

  ```
  class User(BaseModel):
  name: str
  surname: str
  url: str
  age: int
  ```

  debe ser:

  ```
  class User(BaseModel):
      name: str
      surname: str
      url: str
      age: int
  ```

  el sangrado es crucial en Python porque define que va dentro de cada bloque de código. Tu código no generaba ningún error sintáctico, pero la clase `User` no tenia definidos ninguno de los atributos y eso es lo que generaba después el error al instanciarla.
- Por otro lado, el campo para la edad se llama `age` no `Age`, Python es sensible a mayúsculas. Es decir, en vez de:

  ```
  User(name="Flor", surname="Martin", url="...", Age=9)
  ```

  debe ser:

  ```
  User(name="Flor", surname="Martin", url="...", age=9)
  ```

  y lo mismo en el resto de instancias.
- Por ultimo, tienes un error en:

  ```
  @app.get("/Users")
  async def Users():
      return Users(...)
  ```

  estas intentando retornar el retorno de llamar a `Users`, que es el nombre de la propia función asíncrona, debe ser una instancia del modelo, `User`:

  ```
  @app.get("/Users")
  async def Users():
      return User(...)
  ```

El código completo corregido:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

# python -m uvicorn users:app --reload
# para dejar de usar el servidor control c


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    surname: str
    url: str
    age: int


@app.get("/Users_list")
async def Users_list():
    users_list = [
       User(name="Flor", surname="Martin", url="https//mouredev.com", age=9),
       User(name="Fede", surname="Martin", url="https//mouredev.com", age=11),
       User(name="Mirian", surname="Herrera", url="https//mourede2.com", age=49)]
    return users_list


@app.get("/Usersjson")
async def Usersjson():
    return [
        {"name": "Ariel", "surname": "Martin",
         "url": "https//mouredev.com", "age": 45},
        {"name": "Flor", "surname": "Martin",
         "url": "https//mouredev.com", "age": 9},
        {"name": "Fede", "surname": "Martin",
         "url": "https//mouredev.com", "age": 11},
        {"name": "Mirian", "surname": "Herrera",
         "url": "https//mourede2.com", "age": 49}
        ]


@app.get("/Users")
async def Users():
    return User(
        name="Ariel", surname="Martin", url="https//mouredev.com", age=45
        )
```

**Edicion**

En `Users_list` faltaba también retornar la lista, aunque esto generaba una respuesta 200, obviamente no recibirías los datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!! son "detalles" que se me escaparon y son importantes ya voy a ir aprendiendo gracias nuevamente